# How to test In app Billing of existing app on Google Play

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

I have a free app on Google Play, which works normally. I decided to add some features and  user needs to pay to unlock them. So I added In app billing to my app. I want to know: what is the best way to test in app billing in my situation. 
I tried this way: create new application (in the same google play console as existing app) => upload new apk (which includes in app billing) as Alpha version of new Application.

The first time my new app is suspended by Google (because I  use the same logo, screenshots as existing app).

I think if I replace them with other pictures, everything will work.

But I'm not sure that 's right way to test IAB. 
Can anybody give me some advices? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create separate app under different package name. Just increment the version number of the current app and publish it under the same package ID as an alpha version. The in-app billing works fine in both beta and alpha releases.

Comment: My current version is 1.0.1 (production version), what will happen with it if I publish version 1.0.2 (which includes IAB) as Alpha version? Both of them will work?

Comment: I know that the new version (1.0.2 -alpha) will work. But I want to know what happens with official version 1.0.1? People still see it on Google play?

Comment: Yes, the production version will still be visible to users. The alpha version will be visible only to those users who are added to the alpha testing community through Google+. You can find more information in your developer console about alpha/beta testing communities.

Comment: Thanks tomzorb. I will try . Hope everything will be ok